# Wordpress Hosting in Azure with integrated Media Services and Uploader Security

Tags: azure, wordpress, azure-media-services

I'm using a wordpress template and have multiple media uploaders. When they embedd/insert their content from the media library, they should only be able to see and embedd their uploaded content. My goal is to host the website in Azure and also use its media services for video content. Is there an elegant frontend way  with wich users can upload their content an reembedd it after transcoding?

Answer (score 6):

I think that there is no plugin that supports directly Azure Media Services encoding workflows in WordPress.

Maybe you can do it in a few steps :

1. Use the WordPress Azure Storage plugins to upload your files : https://wordpress.org/plugins/windows-azure-storage/
2. Use an Azure WebJob to trigger encoding as soon as a file is uploaded in the storage : https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to.md and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-encode-asset/
3. Display the video on your site, using Azure Media Player : http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/

Hope this helps,

Julien